# How to assign columns from excel to variables in R with a loop?

Tags: r, excel

I am really not good at loop even it is a easy one. From excel, with `col_names=TRUE`, I would like to use each column as an independent variable as x_i with `i in 1:256` and the 257th column as dependent variable. The excel has 257 columns as variables and it looks like this:

```
      1     2    3    4    5        ...      255   256  257
R1   -2.2 -5.4 -1.4 -2.4 -4.9       ...     -8.9  -7.8  69
R2   -1.2 -3.3 -0.5 -1.6 -4.0       ...     -7.0  -5.5  50
R3             ...                             ...
R4             ...                             ...
R5             ...                             ...
```

I tried with

```
>data <- read_excel("data.xlsx",col_names = T) 
>for (i in 1:256) {
 x_i <- data$`i`
 }
```

and end up with

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

And I would like to build a model for example with regression:

```
>y <- data$'257'
>X <- c(x_1,x_2,...,x_256)
>lmr <- lm(y~X)
```

How should I fix it? Should I use a function to assign? Thank you for your help.

Comment: This will clutter your global environment with 256 separate objects (one for each column of the `data` data frame). Instead, why not just use one object--the `data` data frame--and then reference the appropriate column when you need it? If you tell us more about what you're trying to do, we can provide more specific advice.

Comment: To build a regression model, keep your data in a data frame and do this: `lmr = lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=data)`, where `y`, `x1`, `x2`, etc. are names of columns in the `data` data frame. In general, keep your data in a data frame and reference the columns as needed. Like `lm`, many R functions have a `data` argument, which is how you pass the data frame to the function. Then you can use the column names of the data frame in the function.

Comment: To create a large regression formula without having to type in each column name, you can do, for example, this: `lmr = lm(reformulate(names(data)[2:257], response=names(data)[1]), data=data)`. Run `reformulate(names(data)[2:257], response=names(data)[1])` to see the output of `reformulate`.